# What does the mailboxes command do in mutt config?

Tags: configuration, mutt

I'm having a hard time understanding the structure of mutt's configuration. The spoolfile setting is where the list of messages when you first start is located. The folder is the top level directory for choosing folders when you press "c?". What are mailboxes then?

Answer (score 4):

The `mailboxes` command adds the supplied mailbox(es) to the list of mail folders which mutt will monitor for new mail.  The first folder in that list with new mail will be the default choice when you use the `change-folder` command (bound to `c` by default), and you can cycle through all of the mailboxes from that list with new mail by pressing the space bar.  Also, the number of mailboxes in that list with new mail will be available to put into the status bar by using the `%b` format in `$status_format`.